# ConvertTo-Xml Powershell not Working as Expected

Tags: powershell

```
ls | ConvertTo-Xml  # Broken?
ls | ConvertTo-Json # Works
ls | ConvertTo-Html # Works
```

The later works, but the first only ever returns:

```
xml                Objects
---                -------
version="1.0"      Objects
```

Unless I'm being stupid other examples online state that this sort of thing should work.

Comment: The first return `[xml]` object. PowerShell just not display whole XML text of `XmlDocument`.

Comment: @PetSerAl post that as your answer, I'll accept it. The fact it displays only the first line is rubbish and has cost me some time. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Finglas It's not rubbish, it's intended behavior. The entire idea behind PowerShell is that you get a live .NET object back, and not a string

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen while you're right, it's inconsistent given the other Converts display a string on screen hence the confusion.

Comment: There are other inconsistencies as well.  For example, ConvertTo-Json gives you a representation where the property names are dynamic based on the object being serialized.  But with Xml you get a well-defined (and ugly) schema with property and class names being shoved in attribute values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get a text representation use 
`ls | ConvertTo-Xml -As String.`